# Javascript addition

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition is not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript)

In an attempt to learn some java script, I'm trying to build a simple system that adds values when buttons are clicked..

The following code works, but will only add the hardcoded value of `+100`, can anyone help me change this code so it adds the value nested in the `id="add"` button?

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Input tutorial</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
               $(function () {
    $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#total").val(parseInt($("#total").val()) + 100)
});
});
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="button" value="12" id="add">
     <input type="button" value="14" id="total">

  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the hardcoded value of `100` by the value you want:

```
$("#total").val(parseInt($("#total").val()) + parseInt($("#add").val()) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input tutorial</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            $('#add').bind('click', function () {
                $("#total").val(parseInt($("#total").val()) + parseInt($("#add").val()) + 100);
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="12" id="add">
<input type="button" value="0" id="total">
</body>
</html>
```