# Add numbers generated by .js pages

Tags: javascript, math

I have two URLs that are generating subscriber counts.  I'd like to find a way to show their counts added together.

Admittedly, I know little about Javascript, so my attempt hasn't worked.

Here's what I had tried:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
var camp = ['lzlitki','admin_682519'];
var idx = 0;

function next() {
    if ( idx == camp.length ) {
        alert('total '+count);
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
         url:'https://app.getresponse.com/display_subscribers_count.js?campaign_name='+camp[idx++]+'&var=0',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success:function(json){
             count += json.counter;
             next();
         },
         error:function(){
             alert('Error');
         },
    });
}
next();
</script>
```

Would anyone be willing to help me see what's missing?

Comment: What isn't working?  What do you see?

Comment: What happens right now when you run the script?

Comment: Provide more details to get proper answer

Comment: Right now, I get nothing.  It's just blank.

Here is the page on which I've got this:

http://6fig.co/m/bigtest/test.html

Comment: you didn't include jQuery.js on page, if you include it will get alert `total 309`

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do that, honestly.  However, I'll do some research and come back if I can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: look onto [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery by simply adding:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your html (usually in the header).

props to @charlietfl for noticing first.

Comment: Yep, I went and found this, and it worked.

Much appreciated, both you and charlietfl.