# java scripts mathematical equation showing wrong answer

Tags: javascript, math

I am a new learner of Java Script. I'm having a problem with my mathematical equation. Its showing wrong answer.
please help me to find the mistake.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>calculation of (p+r)*(n+r) </title>

        <script>
            function calculate()
            {
               var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
               var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
               var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
               
      
               var calculationa= p+r;
      
      var calculationb= n+r;
     
      
      var cal_final=Number(calculationa)*Number(calculationb);
      
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=cal_final;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>calculation of (p+r)*(n+r)</h1>
        p: <input id="p"><br/>
        n: <input id="n"><br/>
        r: <input id="r"><br/>

       

       <button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is the equation I want to solve.
The math shows this result which is not correct.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir9hs.png

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Hint: all `.value`s are strings, even if they look like numbers.

Comment: `+` before `p` will convert it to `Number` `var calculationa= +p+r;
var calculationb= +n+r;` - Update this two lines!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addition is not working in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are assigned to `p`, `n` and `r` as strings. So, `p+r = 1+2 = 12`.

Use `parseInt()` to parse the values as Integer and do calculations. Or use `parseFloat()`

```js
function calculate() {
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("p").value);
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
  var r = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value);

  var calculationa= p+r;

  var calculationb= n+r;

  var cal_final=Number(calculationa)*Number(calculationb);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=cal_final;
}
```

```html
    <h1>calculation of (p+r)*(n+r)</h1>
    p: <input id="p"><br/>
    n: <input id="n"><br/>
    r: <input id="r"><br/>

   <button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
   <p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also can try this .....

```js
function calculate()
            {              

    var p= Number(document.getElementsByName("p")[0].value); 
    var n= Number(document.getElementsByName("n")[0].value);
    var r= Number(document.getElementsByName("r")[0].value);
    var sum1 = p+ r;
    var sum2 = n+ r;
    var res=sum1 *sum2;

    document.getElementsByName("result1")[0].value = res;
                       
            }
```

```html
 <h1>calculation of (p+r)*(n+r)</h1>
        p: <input type="text"  name="p"><br/>
        n: <input type="text"  name="n"><br/>
        r: <input type="text"  name="r"><br/>
       <br/>
<input type="button" name="add" value ="add" onClick="calculate()" />
result: <input type="text"  name="result1"><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript var value considering as string.

For integer value addition used **parseInt()**.

For Floating  value addition used  **parseFloat()**.

Please check this for more information http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_numbers.htm

```
function calculate()
{
   var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
   var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
   var r = document.getElementById("r").value;


   var calculationa= parseInt(p)+parseInt(r);

   var calculationb= parseInt(n)+parseInt(r);


   var cal_final=parseInt(calculationa)*parseInt(calculationb);

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=cal_final;
}
```