# Looking to make form validation function that checks 2 user inputs

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm working on a side project, a HTML game. The user has 3 buttons to choose from, when they click one it sets an input fields value to that number

I am having trouble with the validation portion of it. I'm very new to javascript so please don't laugh if its a very stupid problem XD.

I've started writing a function it is posted below

```
function Check() {
    var UserInput1 = document.forms["calculator"]["userInput1"];
    var UserInput2 = document.forms["calculator"]["userInput2"];

    var result;

    function Sum(Uval1, Uval2) {
        return Uval1 + Uval2;
    }

    var result = Sum(UserInput1, UserInput2);

    console.log('User Input 1 = ', UserInput1);
    console.log('User Input 2 = ', UserInput2);
    console.log('Result = ', result);
}
```

I want the function to add the 2 user inputs and validate that they are equal to another preset variable in my JS file

Comment: The form control values are strings, so the `+` operator works as concatenation, not addition so you'll get, say, "11" rather than `2`. See [* Addition is not working in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript).

Comment: @RobG So how would I add the 2 values from the form fields?

Comment: Coerce them to number, e.g. `return +Uval1 + +Uval2` or `return Number(Uval1) + Number(Uval2)`. I've suggested a duplicate (now). :-)

Comment: @RobG This is what I keep getting in my Chrome Console "Result =  [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]"

Comment: Oh, sorry! You need to get the value of the inputs: `console.log('User Input 1 = ', UserInput1.value)`.

Comment: document.forms["calculator"]["userInput1"].value

Comment: ```
function Check()                                    
{ 
    var UserInput1 = document.forms["calculator"]["userInput1"].value;
    var UserInput2 = document.forms["calculator"]["userInput2"].value;
    
    var result;
    
    function Sum() {
       
        return UserInput1 + UserInput2;

    }
}

eval("result = Sum(UserInput1, UserInput2);");

``

Okay so I wrote this but I'm a bit confused on what's wrong with this function