# How to compare number to sum of numbers in JS (VUE)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

New to JS and VUE.

I have a variable `numberOfItems` in my data which has `10` as its value.

**I need to compare if this value is equal to the sum of `5` different variables data**

```
var numberOfItems = 10
var destinations = (this.campaign.shipments_ue + this.campaign.shipments_uk + this.campaign.shipments_islas + this.campaign.shipments_peninsula + this.campaign.shipments_international)
```

I get `22222` in `destinations` value instead of `10`, what method should I use to sum them up so I can compare them?

Thanks!

Comment: atleast one of your 5 items is probably a string. If it treats all of them as string, then it adds up all the 2's to get a result of `22222`

Comment: Do I need to convert them to integers?

Comment: Parse a string to number using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addition is not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** Looks like you are adding a string instead of number.

If data type is string then it is resulting of concatenating strings not a number.

**For Ex :**

```js
var num1 = '10', num2 = '20';
console.log(num1 + num2); // 1020 (Here both the variables are string)

num1 = 10;
console.log(num1 + num2); // 1020 (Here variable 1 is number but variable 2 is a string)

num2 = 20;
console.log(num1 + num2); // 30 (Here both the variables are number)
```

Now, As per your requirement. You can use [parseInt()](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function which helps in parsing a string argument and returns an integer.

**Demo :**

```js
var num1 = '10', num2 = '20';

console.log(parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2));
```