# Quick.db .add function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

Im making an addmoney cmd for my discord bot but when the money, it gets added weirdly.
Eg. normally it would be 200 if i add 100 and there was already 100 but im my occasion its 100100.
Anyways code:

```
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db');
const db = new QuickDB();
const discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("You do not have the permissions to use this command.")
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please specify a user❗")

    let user = message.channel.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || messsage.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.member.cache.find(r => r.displayName.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLocaleLowerCase())
    if (!user) return message.reply("Enter a valid user⛔.")
    if (!args[1]) return message.reply("Please specify the amount of money.")
    
    var embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setColor("#C06C84")
       .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
       .setDescription(`Cannot give that much money⛔.
        Please specify a number under 10000.`)
       .setTimestamp()

    if (isNaN(args[1]) ) return message.reply("Your amount is not a number❗.")
    if (args[0] > 10000) return message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
    await db.add(`money_${user.id}`, args[1])
    let bal = await db.get(`money_${user.id}`)

    let moneyEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#C06C84")
        .setDescription(`Gave $${args[1]} \n\nNew Balance: ${bal}`)
    message.reply({embeds: [moneyEmbed]})
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "addmoney",
    category: "economy",
    description: 'Adds money!',
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Addition is not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377410/addition-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could get this kind of behaviour is if `args[1]` was a string. In that case, instead of adding the value, it would just concatenate it with the current value of `money_${user.id}`. So, to fix it all you have to do is, instead of passing it directly, use `parseInt()` and then pass it. Then, your fixed part might look like this =>

```js
await db.add(`money_${user.id}`, parseInt(args[1]))
```